# path of 'jobs' command on linux

Tags: linux

I am doing *myshell* project on systemprogramming course.

I tried to call the *jobs* command using the *execvpe()* function in my shell. I set the path as */usr/bin* as the environment variable.

However, the error message *No Such file or directory* is printed.

Actually, I looked up the *jobs* command in the /*bin* directory and could not find it.

Where can I find the *jobs* command and call it?

Comment: Its handled by the shell.

Comment: So simply use/type: ```help``` or/and ```help jobs``` or/and ```type -a jobs```